# Retrieve All Users From Auth0

Tags: asp.net, auth0

I am using Auth0, And I want to retrieve all users of my client application.

Below is my code:

```
var apiClient = new ManagementApiClient("<<Token>>", new Uri("https://<<Domain>>/api/v2/users"));
var allClients = await apiClient.Users.GetAllAsync();
```

I am using token which includes Read:User permission in auth0.
But I am getting below error,

> Path validation error: 'String does not match pattern ^.+\|.+$: users'
>   on property id (The user_id of the user to retrieve).

I read this arrticle, But I am not understanding, What changes I need to make in auth0.

https://auth0.com/forum/t/auth-renewidtoken-returns-a-user-id-validation-error/1151

What changed I need to make to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `ManagementApiClient` in one of the following ways:

```
// Pass the base Uri of the API (notice it does not include the users path)
var api = new ManagementApiClient("[token]", new Uri("https://[account].auth0.com/api/v2"));
```

**or**

```
// Pass only the domain as a string
var api = new ManagementApiClient("[token]", "[account].auth0.com"));
```

---

You're including `/users` in the base API path which will then cause errors, like the one you observed.